# I'm not alive, but I can be lively

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme, poetry

I come in every shape and every form
In society I'm nothing special I'm the norm
Without me there would be no control
They would die, the things filled with petrol

If a being placed me a specific way
Even though they see me every day
Some beings come to a special place
Just to see me and look at my grace

The ones who would appreciate me the most
They can't see me, because of the ability they lost

Hint 1:

> There is multiple types of me
>  But we're all the same category

Hint 2:

> The last line talks about people who lost sight or **part** of sight

Comment: Any hint? Lots of guesses so far but nothing matches.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are:

> **COLOUR**

*I come in every shape and every form*

> Colour is a property of an object. Every object - no matter what shape or form - could be said to have a colour.

*In society I'm nothing special I'm the norm*

> Colour is everywhere. In demographic terms, a diverse society has people of many races or colours.

*Without me there would be no control*
*They would die, the things filled with petrol*

> Without colour, traffic lights would not work as intended and could not control the flow of traffic, which would grind to a deadlocked standstill ('die').

*If a being placed me a specific way*
*Even though they see me every day*
*Some beings come to a special place*
*Just to see me and look at my grace*

> These lines refer to **art**. Use of colour, through painting, drawing, printing, collage etc. produces many works of art which may be placed in galleries for visitors to appreciate. Colour may be an everyday sight for these people, but its use in a painting can give you a new appreciation for its 'grace'.

*The ones who would appreciate me the most*
*They can't see me, because of the ability they lost*

> Those who are *colour-blind* cannot perceive colour and so would perhaps appreciate being able to see it correctly or as intended more than those who have this facility.

As for the title:

> **Colourful** and **lively** are synonyms...

Comment: Well done. Finally someone figured it out. :)

Answer (score 5):

**You could be**

> Electricity

I come in every shape and every form

> AC current, batteries, lightning, static electricity

In society I'm nothing special I'm the norm

> Everyone has electricity.. well.. almost.

Without me there would be no control
They would die, the things filled with petrol

> The spark that ignites a car's engine

If a being placed me a specific way
Even though they see me every day
Some beings come to a special place
Just to see me and look at my grace

> Lighting instalation/light show, think christmas tree. Which leads to the last point

I'm not alive, but i can be livey
... 
The ones who would appreciate me the most
They can't see me, because of the ability they lost

> Blind people can't see the light.

**Or you could be**

> Fire

I come in every shape and every form

> You have the sun, you have fireworks and plain fire which can encompass whatever it burns regardless of shape

In society I'm nothing special I'm the norm

> Everyone can make a fire

Without me there would be no control
They would die, the things filled with petrol

> Petrol lamps/light sources. If they don't burn, they are dead

If a being placed me a specific way
Even though they see me every day
Some beings come to a special place
Just to see me and look at my grace

> Remember me mentioning fireworks earlier?

I'm not alive, but i can be livey
... 
The ones who would appreciate me the most
They can't see me, because of the ability they lost

> Blind people will not see a candle, a camp fire or  fireworks

Comment: Good try, I like your guess with the electricity, it fits my clues nicely. But I describe something else in my riddle.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it is

> Carbon

I come in every shape and every form

In society I'm nothing special I'm the norm

> Lots of thing made from carbon in our world

Without me there would be no control

They would die, the things filled with petrol

> "The things filled with petrol" could be referring to internal combustion engined vehicles, which would not work without fuel. Alternatively, it could mean all organic life. Being unable to either use vehicles or live could be (weakly) seen as "loss of control"

If a being placed me a specific way

Even though they see me every day

Some beings come to a special place

Just to see me and look at my grace

> Specific placement of carbon atoms leads to diamonds, and people gather at jewellery stores to look at their grace

The ones who would appreciate me the most

They can't see me, because of the ability they lost

> Blind people can't see diamonds? Weak connection here

Comment: Nice try but incorrect. You should also be able to connect it to the title somehow. It has a quite strong connection to the last line.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you are

> **Light**?

*I come in every shape and every form*

> Light reveals every shape and every form.

*In society I'm nothing special I'm the norm*

> Light is normal to have in society, indoors and outdoors (however it is special nonetheless).

*Without me there would be no control*

> Without light, the world will go blind and pretty much become out of control.

*They would die, the things filled with petrol*

> We need light to drive vehicles (that which are filled with petrol) and safely navigate on the roads, as well as travel basically anywhere.

*If a being placed me a specific way* 
*Even though they see me every day* 
*Some beings come to a special place* 
*Just to see me and look at my grace*

> People "place" light on candlewicks particularly in special places such as homes and churches, those of which are holy or sacred or meaningful. Religiously, light is interpreted as a source of grace.

*The ones who would appreciate me the most* 
*They can't see me, because of the ability they lost*

> Unfortunately, people have been born either colour-blind or entirely blind, preventing them from seeing the world — or seeing light in general — the way in which typical people would.

Comment: Good guess, it fits my clues but incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

You could be:

> A shoe

I come in every shape and every form

> Shoes come in many shapes and sizes for various occasions.

In society I'm nothing special I'm the norm

> Shoes are rather commonplace, particularly when one is out and about.

Without me there would be no control
They would die, the things filled with petrol

> Automobiles (AKA, "the things filled with petrol") could hardly go anywhere without the press of a pedal (and, perhaps subjectively, it is easier with a piece of footwear). Stopping is also crucial, and a [brake *shoe*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brake_shoe#targetText=A%20brake%20shoe%20is%20the,train%20brakes%20and%20bicycle%20brakes.) aids in the process.

If a being placed me a specific way
Even though they see me every day
Some beings come to a special place
Just to see me and look at my grace

> This makes me think of a fashion show.

The ones who would appreciate me the most
They can't see me, because of the ability they lost

> I would guess that someone who has lost the ability to walk and is bound to a wheelchair would have less of a reason to examine shoes. (I'll admit that this is a difficult clue to match to my answer...)

Title:

> Put on your [inanimate] shoes and *dance*!

Comment: I like your idea but it's incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Is it:

> Life

I come in every shape and every form
In society I'm nothing special I'm the norm

> Life is everywhere, in many form, and the norm in society.

Without me there would be no control
They would die, the things filled with petrol

> Without life there will be no control, after sometime it become ancient fossilized organic materials or petroleum.

If a being placed me a specific way
Even though they see me every day

> We see life everyday, but some we put on pedestal.

Some beings come to a special place
Just to see me and look at my grace

> We go to the graveyard to honor life passed away

The ones who would appreciate me the most
They can't see me, because of the ability they lost

> We miss life the most when we about to die, we can't see life again simply because we lost it.

Title:

> Life is a concept

Comment: Nice try but not the thing I intended.

Answer (score 0):

Is it:

> Water

I come in every shape and every form
In society I'm nothing special I'm the norm

> Water can come in every shape, and comes in a solid, liquid, gas form.

Without me there would be no control
They would die, the things filled with petrol

> The world would go into chaos, and all the livings things dying would create a lot of petrol. Or perhaps petrol is refering to the color, which could probably be found in some microbes coloring.

If a being placed me a specific way
Even though they see me every day

> Dipends on how water is used, it can be spectacular.

Some beings come to a special place
Just to see me and look at my grace

> Waterparks, waterfalls, damns, ice sculptures, are all things taht can be looked upon even though its just a collection of water.

The ones who would appreciate me the most
They can't see me, because of the ability they lost

> Dead people cant see or taste water.

Title:

> “They both listened silently to the water, which to them was not just water, but the voice of life, the voice of Being, the voice of perpetual Becoming.”― Hermann Hesse

Answer (score 0):

Is it

> the human body?

I'm not alive, but I can be lively

> The body itself is not really "alive," but it is "lively" because of the spirit that inhabits it

I come in every shape and every form

> Lots of different types of human bodies on planet Earth

In society I'm nothing special I'm the norm

> People are everywhere, and so are their bodies

Without me there would be no control

> We wouldn't be able to interact with the physical world without our bodies

They would die, the things filled with petrol

> Cars wouldn't work without people to drive them (as of yet, anyway)

If a being placed me a specific way
Even though they see me every day
Some beings come to a special place
Just to see me and look at my grace

> This could refer to models, actors, shows, and dance, which all celebrate and showcase the human body and its beauty

The ones who would appreciate me the most
They can't see me, because of the ability they lost

> When you die, you lose your body and can't see it anymore

Answer (score 0):

> Glass

I come in every shape and every form
In society I'm nothing special I'm the norm

> Windows, etc.

Without me there would be no control
They would die, the things filled with petrol

> ...Um... Reaching! ...Nothing but a weak bunch of maybes...

If a being placed me a specific way
Even though they see me every day

> Glasses improve eyesight? Crystal refraction is pretty?

Some beings come to a special place
Just to see me and look at my grace

> Glass museums?

The ones who would appreciate me the most
They can't see me, because of the ability they lost

> Glasses are useless to the blind.